# Proving $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous for all $x \ne 0$

Tags: calculus

This is a homework assignment, and I just need a nudge in the right direction. Part (a) asks to show that $\frac{1}{|x|} < \frac{2}{|c|}$, when $|x - c| < \frac{|c|}{2}$. So I took the second part of that statement, and raised it to the -1 power: $$\frac{1}{|x - c|} < \frac{2}{|c|},$$ which *almost* looks like what I need. Tips to get to the end of part (a)?

NOTE: he also gives us a hint, that $\left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{c}\right| = \frac{1}{|c|}\frac{1}{|x|}|x -c|$.

Answer (score 0):

The map $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{ 0 \}$; let $c \neq 0$. If $|x-c| < \frac{|c|}{2}$, then 
$$
|c| - |x| \leq |c-x| = |x-c| < \frac{|c|}{2},
$$
so

$|x| > \frac{|c|}{2},$ and hence
$$
\frac{1}{|x|} < \frac{2}{|c|}.
$$

Comment: Welcome any comments!